# How to prevent outputing the html label?

Tags: php

The code I currently have is:

```
<h2 id="comment_title">vistor comments</h2>  
<div class="count">
  <?php 
    $count = comment_num($nid);
    if($count>0){
        echo $count'comments';
    } else {
        echo '';        
    }
  ?>
</div>
```

Now, i want to know how to alter the above code to get this effect:

When `$count > 0`, it should output the html label, and can use some css style to it.

```
<h2 id="comment_title">vistor comments</h2>and $count'comments';
```

When `$count <= 0`, don't output the html label. and don't use any css style to it.

```
<h2 id="comment_title">vistor comments</h2> ;
```

Comment: `if($count>0){//put everything here you want to echo }`

Comment: `else { echo ''; }` is useless; you can just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2 id="comment_title"><?php echo $count?> visitor comments</h2></div>
```